# Change HTML in Angular 7 by reference

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm passing UL by reference in an Angular function and I want to append some 'li' in that UL.

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="FileUploaded">
              <tr class="" *ngFor="let row of this.fileJson">
                <td class="text-left">{{row.Comment}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">

                  <div class="tags">
                    <ul class="tags tags--ds ui-sortable" #forAddingTag> // This is the reference which is passed in below button's function named "AddTag()"
                      <ng-container *ngFor="let key of this.Object.keys(row)">
                        <li #ToRemoveTag class="tags__item" *ngIf="key.substring(0,5)=='Topic'">
                          <p>{{row[key]}}</p> <span class="close__item"><i class="fal fa-times"
                              (click)="removeTag(ToRemoveTag)"></i></span>
                        </li>
                      </ng-container>

                    </ul>
                  </div>

                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <a class="btn" (mousedown)="AddTag(forAddingTag)">Update</a> // Here the reference is being passed
                </td>

              </tr>

            </ng-container>
```

Here is the typescript code

```
AddTag(evalue){
    debugger

      var text = "";
      if (window.getSelection) {
          text = window.getSelection().toString();
      } 
      var value = text;

  }
```

I just want to add some more "li" at the end of this UL. I can do it with the help of JQuery but it shouldn't be used in Angular.

Comment: you need to get into the angular mindset that "your model === your view" if you want to add another row to a list in an ngFor, you add another item to the list in the model the ngFor is generated from.  Get out of the jquery thinking. in this case, you need to add another key to the row item in `fileJson` (also look into the `keyvalue` pipe)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not to run any function in the `*ngFor` tag. It'll be called too many times than you think it does. Better way would be to create another object in the controller (something like `filteredRows`) and loop over it in the template with the `keyvalue` pipe.

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="FileUploaded">
  <tr class="" *ngFor="let row of filteredRows; let rowIndex=index">
    <td class="text-left">{{ row.comment }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <div class="tags">
        <ul class="tags tags--ds ui-sortable" #forAddingTag>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let topic of filteredRows.topics | keyvalue; let topicIndex=index">
            <li #ToRemoveTag class="tags__item">
              <p>{{ topic.value }}</p> <span class="close__item"><i class="fal fa-times"(click)="removeTag(rowIndex, topicIndex)"></i></span>
            </li>
          </ng-container>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td class="text-center">
      <a class="btn" (mousedown)="addTag(rowIndex)">Update</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Then you could modify the `filteredRows` variable (add/remove properties) to reflect the changes in the template.

Controller

```js
filteredRows: {comment: any, topics: any[]}[];

ngOnInit() {
  fileJson.forEach(row => {
    const comment = row['Comment'];
    const topics = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row));    // <-- create a deep copy of `row` object
    for (const key in topics) {
      if (topics.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (key.substring(0, 5) !== 'Topic') {
          delete topics[key];
        }
      }
    }
    this.filteredRows.push({comment: comment, topics: topics});
  });
}

addTag(index) {
  this.filteredRows[index].topics.push(
    {
      // object content
    }
  );
}

removeTag(rowIndex, topicIndex) {
  delete this.filteredRows[rowIndex].topics[topicIndex];
}
```

---

<sup>Function name `AddTag()` goes against the usual convention of camel case naming for functions.</sup>

Comment: Your code would work if 'row' was a simple object. But it is actually coming from the ngFor loop from the top. I have edited the code for you to see.

Comment: You could again modify the data structure in the controller to make it easier in the template's side. I've modified the answer. Please see if it works for you. Judging by the code, we could possibly improve it more if you were to show more code. But I'll leave it to you. Just remember in Typescript you have more control over the type of the data than JS.